# como se puede obtener la url de una pagina en incognito con una extension de chrome?

Tags: javascript, chrome, extensiones

Estoy desarrollando una extension en chrome y necesito obtener la url de la pagina, utilizo el siguiente codigo

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
 tab = tabs[0]
 console.log(tab['url'])
 url_tab = tab['url'] 
 validar(url_tab)
});
```

esto me funciona pero solo en las ventanas "normales" y no en las de incognito.
cuando estoy en incognito me muestra la url de la pagina en la que estoy en la otra ventana "normal"
Hay alguna forma de obtener la url en incognito?

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true,'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}, function(tabs) {
chrome.windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});
 tab = tabs[0]
 console.log(tab['url'])
 url_tab = tab['url'] 
 validar(url_tab)
});
```

revisa esta pregunta
[stackOverflow en ingles, pregunta , chrome modo incognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002830/open-up-two-tabs-in-a-new-chrome-incognito-window)